Sum of the Digits
I know this is perhaps a pretty bizarre question, but it was inspired from an old BMO problem.

Let $f(n) = 3n^2 + n + 1$, and let $S(n)$ be the sum of the digits of $n$.  Is it true that for every positive integer $k$ there are only finitely-many positive integers $n$ such that $S(f(n))=k$?

For small values of $k$, this holds, but it is unclear to me what will happen for larger values. Will there always be finitely-many solutions, because $f(n)$ needs to equal some sort of exponential-like function?

I don't understand what you mean by "for small values of $n$, this holds".  There are only finitely many "small values of $n$" so, what are you claiming?  Did you mean "for small values of $k$"?  How do you prove that, for say $k=1$ or $k=2$?

Yes, that was a mistake in my phrasing. It is a good exercise to look at $k = 1$ and $k = 2$. Just going into $k = 1$, this occurs when you have a power of ten. There are no positive integer solutions to $f(n) = 1$, and notice that larger powers of $10$ are always even, but f(n) always returns an odd number. So for k = 1, there are no positive integers n.

1/ You should quote the exact BMO question. 2/ Clearly $k=5$ has infintily many solutions.

Unfortunately for your question you don't have discarded the digit $0$. Anyway, perhaps you can edited your problem in whose case I believe you will be right.

It's certainly not true for all $k$.  Indeed, it seems to be more the exception than the rule.  For instance, there are infinitely many solutions to $S(f(n))=5$.  One infinite family is found at $n=10^{a}$ ($a\ge 1$), since $$f(10^a)=3\cdot 10^{2a}+10^{a}+1=300\ldots00100\ldots001.$$
There will be many other such infinite families (for different small values of $k$), which you can find by looking at numbers of the form $A\cdot 10^a + B$.  Indeed, all values of $k$ that can be expressed in the form $S(3A^2) + S(6AB + A) + S(3B^2 + B + 1)$, for integer $A>0$ and $B\ge 0$, will work.  This seems to cover all positive $k$ except for
$$
k \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14 \};
$$
and of course some of these may still lead to infinite families of a different form.

No. For $k=5,$ there are infinitely many solutions.

Note that $S(f(10^{m}))=5.$

Thus, setting $k=5,$ we find that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $S(f(n))=5.$

Should I delete my answer? You've rephrased what I wrote.

Are there any other values of k? Edit: yeah multiple of powers of 10 work

Well, we can generalize this idea to $n=2(10^{m})$ for large $m$, and so on. So, for example, the problem for k=6 has infinitely many solutions.
